# dc.js- handling millions of records by crossfiltering at server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have been using `dc.js` for the past 2 months. It is an excellent visualization library. Recently, I was forced to feed millions of records to my dashboards.

Now,the browser is lagging to get filtered.
I have googled a little and came to know that we can do cross filtering at server side which greatly increases the performance. Is there any working implementation which would be of great help?? Thanks in advance...